# how to install and run 'tlssled' in the ubuntu machine

Tags: ubuntu, tls, sled

tlssled works fine in Kali-linux, but not in Ubuntu. Is it by default , tlsseld is not installed in Ubuntu? Is tlssled supported in Ubuntu? If yes, how to install?

My Ubuntu machine:

```
root@machine ~:uname -r
3.13.0-98-generic
root@machine ~:cat /etc/*-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="12.04.5 LTS, Precise Pangolin"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu precise (12.04.5 LTS)"
VERSION_ID="12.04"
```

Please let me know how to install and run the tlssled command.

Thanks in advance, Subhash

Comment: [TLSSLed 1.3](http://www.taddong.com/tools/TLSSLed_v1.3.sh)                  chmod +x TLSSLed_v1.3.sh                                                                       sudo cp TLSSLed_v1.3.sh /usr/bin/                                                              sudo cp TLSSLed_v1.3.sh /usr/local/bin

Answer (score 0):

Copy the [tlssled](http://www.taddong.com/tools/TLSSLed_v1.3.sh) to /usr/bin

```
#/usr/bin/tlssled <ip address> 1300
#------------------------------------------------------
#TLSSLed - (1.3) based on sslscan and openssl
#by Raul Siles (www.taddong.com)
#------------------------------------------------------
#[!] ERROR: sslscan command not found!
```

we need to install sslscan, use

```
sudo apt-get install sslscan
```